# Read XML File in C# with same node name

Tags: c#, xml

I need to read a XML file that has nodes with the same name. 
Can't figure how to accomplish the task.
I've got a class of Person which contains two fields:

1. PersonID
2. HubbyList - List of hubbies object

XML:

```
<group>
  <person>
    <id>1</id>
    <hubby>
      <id>1</id>
    </hubby>
    <hubby>
      <id>2</id>
    </hubby>
    <hubby>
      <id>3</id>
    </hubby>
    <hubby>
      <id>4</id>
    </hubby>
  </person>
  <person>
    <id>2</id>
    <hubby>
      <id>1</id>
    </hubby>
    <hubby>
      <id>2</id>
    </hubby>
  </person>
</group>
```

Comment: What is your current code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you show how far you've got? Are you using LINQ to XML for example? You could find each `person` element with `doc.Root.Elements("person")` and the `hubby` elements within each person element with `person.Elements("hubby")`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,get your model of xml structure from [here](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/).

```
        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "hubby")]
        public class Hubby
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "person")]
        public class Person
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "hubby")]
            public List<Hubby> Hubby { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "group")]
        public class Group
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "person")]
            public List<Person> Person { get; set; }
        }
```

Then, You can do it like this:

```
        var stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("path"));
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Group));
        var data = serializer.Deserialize(stringReader) as Group;
        // get all hubby of first person 
        var hubbies = data.Person[0].Hubby;
```